# Paymill 3-D secure enabled/disabled?

Tags: magento-1.8, payment-gateway

What is the difference between 3-D secure enabled/disabled in magento paymill payment module? It is necessary to enter the code from credit card code generator every time if 3-D secure is enabled? Can I expect less checkout conversion with 3-D secure enabled?

3-D Secure info sheet is available here: [click](https://www.paymill.com/downloads/pm_infoblatt-3DSecure-EN_130115.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known that 3D secure can drastically reduce checkout conversion rates due to the extra step and annoyance it add into the checkout. It does however drastically reduce the risk of fraud to your business whilst giving customers the confidence that you are on top of fraud.

The 3D secure page will only be displayed if the customers card is enrolled in the service. Otherwise the checkout should complete as if it were disabled.

Answer (score 0):

every client using a 3DS enrolled CC will have to enter his authorization code. However, only if you also enabled 3DS for your PAYMILL account!
Of course, if a client of yours has already authorized his CC once he can go through the fast-checkout mode and simply confirm the purchase without having to enter his CC details/authorization code again.

Best, Nicolas (PAYMILL Support)

support@paymill.de